# jQuery find stopped working and element looks strange

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found that some production jQuery code stopped working.
The code is very simple, it just finds the nested elements with specific class:

```
var richTextImages = element.find('.rich-text-image');
```

Btw, this code works:

```
var richTextImages = element.find('img');
```

And it finds all the images with the class above.
It works perfectly locally and in some other prod source. There is no difference in the code neither in the layout.
Another strange thing I found is how jQuery represents element. 
In the working code it looks like this one:
[image]

Non-working element looks like this one:

[image]

Another thing I would like to note is both elements are rendered within AngularJS directive.

I suspect now maybe some other embed code (I have facebook button and disqus may interfere but I don't know for sure).

Comment: Are you sure `element` is a jQuery object? Meaning is it possible some other library is loaded and `element` is created from that library and has similar methods like `find`. For instance AngularJS has a `find()` method: [__find() - Limited to lookups by tag name__](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#methods%23angularjs-s-jqlite)

Comment: @PatrickEvans, thanks for the idea! Do you know how to make sure that the element is jQuery one or not?

Comment: You have to make sure jQuery is loaded before AngularJS, so put the script for it above angular's. That should make it so it uses jQuery instead of Angular's jqLite

Comment: @PatrickEvans THANKS! It worked! Can you add your advice as an answer that I would be able to mark it as a solution?